# Android project won't implement interface

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have 2 interfaces 
My main activity implements both of them but for some reason it says can't resolve symbol

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SubmitCallbackListener,
    StartOverCallbackListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
implements code();
}
public interface StartOverCallbackListener {
public void onStartOver();
}
public interface SubmitCallbackListener {

public void onSubmit();

}
```

and yes all interfaces and activities are in the same directory. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the exact error? [The full error also tends to give a line where the error occurs, which should help you too]

Comment: It says can not resolve symbol. All my fragments and intefaces say the same problem in the main activity

Comment: Please include the logcat

Comment: @Azeal, I believe this is before even trying to compile. More of a reference to Android Studios. Joe, hopefully my answer helps out, although your description of the error is still vague. How do the fragments and interfaces exactly "say" the same problem? Is the IDE giving the errors along the interface? Along the fragments? On the main activity's implement line? Is there only one error, and is it the same word-for-word? On a side note, it sounds like the fragments are a sub-class of your Activity, which I hope is not the case.

Comment: I try to build and it says that it can't find symbol during the build and fails

Comment: We need all those errors that tells you that it fails. If you can't, add screenshots. Also, did you try the answer below yet?

Comment: I fixed it by making a blank project and just copy pasting my code in

Comment: So it was an IDE-based error. By the way, if you run into something similar like this where it won't build and you have no idea why, 1) Restart Android Studio and 2) Run "Clean project" from under the "Build" menu [under the top bar]

Comment: I did that didn't work so I don't know what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely concerned with not even being able to find the interfaces. However, you can easily take advantage of Android Studio's features to correct this.

Erase all the implements [ie "`implements SubmitCallbackListener...`" and such]. Then, add them one by one and use Android Studio's little pop-up complete feature to get the names/paths of the implementations. Then, if there's still some red underlining, click to the right of the implementation's name until the red lightbulb pops up at the beginning of the line (which describes the error usually). Click it, and it should give you an option to "implement methods." Use that, if necessary.

Note that if the listener doesn't pop up when you try to type in the name of the implementation, it may be that the current Activity/fragment can't access it.